# How to add page number in footer using JavaScript or CSS while print?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want there should be page counter in footer right, I am using Chrome. I know there is option available in more settings of Chrome but it also print URL which I don't want in print pages. Plus if printing date also display it will be awesome.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

An example snippet:

HTML

```
<div id="pageFooter">Page </div>
```

CSS

```
#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}
```

Please let me know if this resolves your issue.